# Como usar htaccess en las URLs

Tags: php, html, web

quisiera saber como podria cambiar las URLs de mi web tipo /login.php a unicamente /login. Se me ocurrio hacer una carpeta por cada archivo de estos y hacer un index.php, pero no querria hacer eso y que quedara sin el formato del archivo, que fuera todo /login, /foro, y asi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para eliminar la extensión `.php` de un archivo PHP, por ejemplo tusitio.com/login.php en tusitio.com/login, tienes que agregar esto al `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Lo mismo si quieres que sea para `.html`

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

De todas formas, para hacer URLs amigables no siempre has de usar el `.httaccess`. Échale un ojo al concepto, se pueden hacer mil cosas como por ejemplo añadir los parámetros como apartados `tusitio.com/login/Kranex95/`